# Issues setting up Salesforce communities using one of the self-service templates(Napili)

Tags: community, configuration, site.com, page-template

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience setting up a community using the new self-service templates. I personally have set-up Salesforce community in the past using the "Salesforce tabs + visualforce" template but I'm running into a bit of an issue with the new templates specifically **Napili** in my **Sandbox org**. I have a "Napili" templatized community but when I log in I land on a page that says **URL No Longer Exists** and the URL is in the form **https://mycommunityname/name/s**. In the Community Builder, I am unable to publish the "**Home**" page in order to test and see if the reason why I get the error is due to the page not being published. Anyone have any input or experience on this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a developer org and spinning up a new community with the Napili template. However, unlike in my sandbox, I was actually able to publish the Home page in my dev org from the Community Builder. I went back and logged in as a community user and everything worked fine - no more URL No Longer Exists.

Comment: Just as an update - since summer 15, you can now publish site pages in sandboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't publish a Community in a sandbox.

[Partner Community User unable to login gets error- URL no longer exists](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193739)